# Add-AzureRmAccount : Sequence contains no element (Not working for Gmail accounts too)

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I have created a 'Free Trial' account with my personal email ID which is a Gmail ID. I'm getting the error :

> Add-AzureRmAccount : Sequence contains no elements At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureRMAccountCommand

The code I'm running is

```
$username = "abc@gmail.com"
$password = "something"

$secpass = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secpass

Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
```

Are there certain type of accounts/subscriptions for which logging in like this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Live ID credentials cannot be used for a non-interactive login. This error message is described as part of [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/2915) which has been raised because it needs improving.

I think you either need to use `Login-AzureRmAccount` to login interactively or create a Service Principal for login, per this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azurermps-4.2.0

> **Log in with a service principal**
>
> Service principals provide a way for you to create non-interactive
>   accounts that you can use to manipulate resources. Service principals
>   are like user accounts to which you can apply rules using Azure Active
>   Directory. By granting the minimum permissions needed to a service
>   principal, you can ensure your automation scripts are even more
>   secure.
>
> 1. If you don't already have a service principal, [create one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azurermps-4.2.0).
> 2. Log in with the service principal:
>
>    ```
>    Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -ApplicationId  "http://my-app" -Credential $pscredential -TenantId $tenantid
>    ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mark! 

Just to clarify, using a gmail account counts as using Windows Live ID credentials?

Comment: Yes, you can use any email address to create a Windows Live ID afaik.

Comment: It'd be great if you could also shed light on what are the kind of accounts that are allowed non-interactive login and how I can create one.

Comment: Seemingly organisational accounts (e.g a work or school account from a custom domain) or a service principal (as described in the answer above).